# Calcular un dato y almacenarlo en la misma fila del dato insertado trigger

Tags: sql, trigger

como puedo modificar solamente el dato de la fila ingresada
tengo un trigger el cual  realiza un calculo y todo funciona bien pero quiero que ese resultado se almacene solamente en la fila y no en toda la columna como me esta pasando en este momento

**parte del codigo**

```
If @Inicial1>@final1

SET  @MES1 = 0

else 

SET  @MES1 =datediff(Day,@final1,@inicial1)
 

update Agentes_Ausentismos  set mes1 = @MES1;


END
```

aqui despues de calcular varias cosas quiero almacenar @mes1 en la columna mes1 pero al realizar el update me llena toda la columna y quiero que solo se llene la fila que acabe de insertar

gracias de antemano

Comment: mmm... estas repitiendo la pregunta? porque esto mismo lo veniamos discutiendo en otro lado...

Comment: Motor de BD? Recuerda que no todos tienen que saber que esto viene de otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que a esa tabla donde le haces el `INSERT` tiene un índice, solo tendrías que recuperar el último índice que se generó para esa tabla y agregar a tu `UPDATE` un `WHERE`; que queda algo como esto:

```sql
If @Inicial1>@final1

SET  @MES1 = 0

else 

SET  @MES1 =datediff(Day,@final1,@inicial1)
 

update Agentes_Ausentismos 
set mes1 = @MES1 
where indice = IDENT_CURRENT('Agentes_Ausentismos');


END
```

> Donde dice `WHERE indice = IDENT_CURRENT('Agentes_Ausentismos')`, la palabra indice representa al nombre de la columna que almacena los índices de tu tabla.
> Con el `INDET_CURRENT('Agentes_Ausentismos')` obtendrás el último ID generado.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando es un trigger hay una tabla "auxiliar" para estos casos, la tabla se llama "inserted" esta tabla tiene los datos que se están insertando o actualizando, también cuenta con la misma estructura de la tabla en cuestión. Necesitas hacer referencia a esa table mediante el ID de la tabla si es que tiene un id, o buscar la forma de relacionar la tabla, un ejemplo sería así:

```
update a set mes1 = @MES1;
from Agentes_Ausentismos a
inner join inserted b on a.ID=b.ID
```

De esta forma actualizaras únicamente el o los registros que se este insertando u actualizando, como te comente yo estoy uniendo las tablas por un campo "ID" ya que no se que campos tiene tu tabla Agentes_Ausentismos, pero tienes que cambiarlo por el campo que los relacione, espero te ayude.